# variable coefficients of second and third order linear differentail equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Are there any real-life Applications of second Order and Third order ODEs with variable coefficients ?? any help mentioning those Applications?

Comment: Try to search for Moore-Gibson-Thompson thermoelasticity. That should answer your question.

Comment: Hamdiken thank you sir. Can you add one more application plz. Apart from that given application-moore-gibson-thampson...like application from enegeering or fluid mechanics something like that .. thanks